# Time Duration between 2 DateTimes in PHP is not accurate when over a day has past

Tags: php, datetime

I am working on a Timeclock application for my boss and I store a clock in and clock out time as a DateTime and as a Timestamp.

Below is a simple function to calculate the duration between a user's Clock in and Clock out DateTimes.

In the demo you can see the result is `15:11:18` even though there is like 5 days between the 2 dates.  I know I could simply make the function show the number of days but my boss does not want to show days, instead this should should the Total Hour, minutes,  seconds between the 2 DateTimes and not show the Days.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or help to make it show the proper amount of time?

For example 2 extra days would add 48 hours to the Hours instead of 2 days

```
public function dateTimeDifference($startDatetime, $endDatetime, $format = '%H:%I:%S')
{
    $startDatetime2 = new DateTime($startDatetime, $this->timeZone);
    $endDatetime2 = new DateTime($endDatetime, $this->timeZone);
    $interval = $startDatetime2->diff($endDatetime2);

    return $interval->format($format);

}

$startDatetime = '2013-09-10 07:15:48 pm';
$endDatetime = '2013-09-15 10:27:06 am'; 

echo dateTimeDifference($startDatetime, $endDatetime)

// Result:   15:11:18
```

Comment: Another way is to move such tasks to DBMS. They are more accurate with such data.

Answer (score 2):

Change the format of `function variable $format` like

```
$format = '%d days %H:%I:%S'

public function dateTimeDifference($startDatetime, $endDatetime, $format = '%d days %H:%I:%S')
{
    $startDatetime2 = new DateTime($startDatetime, $this->timeZone);
    $endDatetime2 = new DateTime($endDatetime, $this->timeZone);
    $interval = $startDatetime2->diff($endDatetime2);

    return $interval->format($format);

}

$startDatetime = '2013-09-10 07:15:48 pm';
$endDatetime = '2013-09-15 10:27:06 am'; 

echo dateTimeDifference($startDatetime, $endDatetime);
```

If you want to convert the `days` to `hours` then try this,

```
function dateTimeDifference($startDatetime, $endDatetime, $format = '%H:%I:%S')
{
    $startDatetime2 = new DateTime($startDatetime);
    $endDatetime2 = new DateTime($endDatetime);
    $interval = $startDatetime2->diff($endDatetime2);
    $d=$interval->format('%d');
    $format=$interval->format($format);
    $f=explode(':',$format);
    $td=$d*24;
    return $time=($f[0]+$td).':'.$f[1].':'.$f[2];

}

$startDatetime = '2013-09-10 07:15:48 pm';
$endDatetime = '2013-09-15 10:27:06 am'; 

echo dateTimeDifference($startDatetime, $endDatetime);
// 111:11:18
```

Comment: Thanks I understand how to display the total days, my goal is to NOT show the days and instead add the days as Hours to the hours total.  So 2 extra days would add 48 hours to the `H` hours

Comment: Beat me to it. :-) Good answer! Though I'd remove the `$format` string from the function and hardcode it, since the rest of the code now depends on the format being `'%H:%I:%S'`

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are formatting the difference as %H:%i:%s, which is the hours, minutes, and seconds. To get the number of days, you will need the `%D` part.

If you want the number of days converted to hours, you will need to perform your own calculations on that and change the format to not include the hour part.

```
public function dateTimeDifference($startDatetime, $endDatetime, $format = '%I:%S')
{
    $startDatetime2 = new DateTime($startDatetime, $this->timeZone);
    $endDatetime2 = new DateTime($endDatetime, $this->timeZone);
    $interval = $startDatetime2->diff($endDatetime2);

    $hours = $interval->format("%H") + ($interval->format("%d") * 24);
    return $hours . ':' . $interval->format($format);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best and easiest way would be to overwrite $interval -> h

```
public function dateTimeDifference($startDatetime, $endDatetime, $format = '%H:%I:%S')
{
    $startDatetime2 = new DateTime($startDatetime, $this->timeZone);
    $endDatetime2 = new DateTime($endDatetime, $this->timeZone);
    $interval = $startDatetime2->diff($endDatetime2);
    $interval -> h += 24 * $interval -> days;

    return $interval->format($format);

}
```